# Jenkins 'pscp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: jenkins, devops

I am running this script in jenkins on Windows. Calling it with bat.

folder: Jenkins\workspace\FullyAutomated>

command:

```
pscp -scp -i ..\..\keys\key.ppk webapp\target\webapp.war ec2-user@x.xx.xxx.xxx:~/apache-tomcat-8.5.54/webapps
```

Error:

```
'pscp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am able to run it locally from that folder on my machine and it works. However I would like to get it to work with jenkins.

Do I need to install a plugin?

Comment: Sounds like `pscp` is not on your PATH on the user that's running the Jenkins service.

Comment: Ah ok ill add it to the jenkins PATH envs

Comment: not sure how to add it

Comment: also the job is running on admin user, how do i allow the user to use pscp on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right. The only problem is that you need to configure path to your putty files binary directory.

The link bellow explais how to do.
https://www.pc-freak.net/blog/windows-add-command-path-variable-adding-folder-windows-path/

Comment: You should consider quoting the relevant text from the blog in-line in your answer to prevent [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Comment: It worked locally so is there another location for Jenkins to read from?

Comment: @AdamSmith how do i add it to the Path for that user. User admin is running the jenkins job.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Jenkins fixed it. But I made sure to have putty in the PATH variable.